# Filter out API results

Tags: c#, winforms, api

I have a list of information that comes from an API.
I want to filter out certain things for a ListBox. I have made a `public string` for this and added the information I wanted in the list.
Now the way I have it set up it shows the information I would like, but leaves empty spaces in the ListBox.
I want to get rid of this spaces in the ListBox. I have tried to return a `null` and a `string.Empty`

```
get 
{
    if( Status == 1)
    {
        string queues = $"{SSDocument.SSDocumentID} | {LastActionUser} | {LastAccessed} | {Queue.Name}";
        return queues;
    }
    else 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Information using the GET:

```
public void DocumentList(int sender)
{
    if (sender == 1)
    {
        StatusList f = new StatusList();
        f.Show();

        st = rClient.makeRequest(S9());
        f.listBox1.DataSource = st;
        f.listBox1.DisplayMember = "QueueList";
    }
}
```

Request for `rClient.makeRequest(s9())`:

```
public List<stats> makeRequest(string endPoint)
{
    signOn so = new signOn();
    string strResponseVlaue = string.Empty;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
    request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();
    request.Method = "GET";
    string userName = so.grabUser();
    string passWord = so.grabPass();
    string domain = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{domain}{userName}:{passWord}"));

    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Error Code: " + response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }

        //Process the response stream
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (responseStream != null)
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    strResponseVlaue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        } //End of Response Stream
    }// End Of Using Reponse
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<stats>>(strResponseVlaue);
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Where's the code where you actually remove things from the list?

Comment: You are talking about code we can't see.  We don't know what's going on in `st = rClient.makeRequest(S9());`  which seems to be the source of your issue.

Comment: @LarsTech it is to make the API call and then it deserializes the JSON and then puts it into the list. Everything works, I just want to eliminate the spaces in the listbox. I get the displayed results I want, but it also creates an entry for the Null values. I guess I may not be understanding why that is important.

Comment: Because `rClient.makeRequest(S9())` returns some kind of list.  We don't know anything about this list.  Is it a DataTable?  A Class?

Comment: @LarsTech I have updated to reflect the request.

Comment: Maybe add a filter like this: `f.listBox1.DataSource = st.Where(cls => cls.Status == sender).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getter of a class property used as the **`DisplayMember`** of a ListBox control, tries to filter out the elements that do not satisfy a condition.
The condition is verified in the property getter, forcing to return `null` or `string.Empty` when the current element doesn't satisfy the condition.

This behaviour produces empty elements in the ListBox.

The proposed solution is, of course, to pre-filter the elements that define the ListBox data source before the property  used as `DisplayMember`, can format the elements to display:

```
[ListBox].DataSource = st.Where(cls => [Condition]).ToList();
```

A probaly better solution is to build a class that can perform the filtering on its own.
An example:

```
int Sender = 1;

TestClass test = new TestClass();
test.AddRange(new []
{
    new TestClass() { Status = 0, QueueName = "Queue1", SSDocumentID = 1 },
    new TestClass() { Status = 1, QueueName = "Queue1", SSDocumentID = 1 },
    new TestClass() { Status = 1, QueueName = "Queue2", SSDocumentID = 2 },
    new TestClass() { Status = 0, QueueName = "Queue3", SSDocumentID = 3 },
    new TestClass() { Status = 1, QueueName = "Queue4", SSDocumentID = 4 },
});

listBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayMember";
listBox1.DataSource = test.Filter(Sender).ToList();

public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass() => this.Members = new List<TestClass>();
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int SSDocumentID { get; set; }
    public string QueueName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayMember => $"{this.SSDocumentID} | {this.QueueName}";

    public List<TestClass> Members { get; }
    public void Add(TestClass element) => this.Members.Add(element);
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TestClass> elements) => 
        this.Members.AddRange(elements.ToArray());
    public IEnumerable<TestClass> Filter(int status)
    {
        if (this.Members.Count == 0) return null;
        return this.Members.Where(st => st.Status == status);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I had the list pre-built, I had to make modifications like this `f.listBox1.DataSource = st.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.QueueList)).ToList()`

Comment: Sure. But, following the example I posted, you could also have `[TestClass].AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<stats>>(strResponseVlaue));`. So you could handle the deserialized JSON results on your own terms from the beginning. Of course, I know nothing about the complex of your application.